Cannot find package
Libraries and communications:

typescript v5.4.5
node v20.11.1
pnpm v9.1.0
ts-node v10.9.2
nodemon v3.1.3

On Stack Overflow, I found a similar problem and solved it, but there is another problem where I can't solve it or find it, I used a node project to run discord.js bot, but because of my imports I couldn't run the code, the script used is "dev", my package.json:
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec node --experimental-loader ts-node/esm src/middleware.ts",
    "knip": { "knip": "knip",
    "knip:fix": "knip --fix",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts"
  },

code:
import { client, Next } from '@/app';
import { CheckBasicDiscordGuild, SubBuffer } from '@/components';

// Handle unhandled promise rejections and uncaught exceptions
process.on('unhandledRejection', SubBuffer);
process.on('uncaughtException', SubBuffer);

const BooleanParam = await CheckBasicDiscordGuild(client);

if (BooleanParam === true) Next(client);

tsconfig.json & tsconfig.paths.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "strict": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "declarationMap": false,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "newLine": "crlf",
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "ESNext"
    ],
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build"
  ],
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json"
}

{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@base/*": ["./*"],
      // "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      // "@app/*": ["./src/app/*"],
      // "@constants/*": ["./src/constants/*"],
      // "@database/*": ["./src/database/*"],
      // "@handlers/*": ["./src/handlers/*"],
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}

error:
> nodemon --exec node --experimental-loader ts-node/esm src/middleware.ts

[nodemon] 3.1.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter \`rs\`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[nodemon] starting \`node --experimental-loader ts-node/esm src/middleware.ts\`
(node:15548) ExperimentalWarning: \`--experimental-loader\` may be removed in the future; instead use \`register()\`:
--import 'data:text/javascript,import { register } from "node:module"; import { pathToFileURL } from "node:url"; register("ts-node/esm", pathToFileURL("./")));'
(Use \`node --trace-warnings ...\` to show where the warning was created)

node:internal/process/esm_loader:34
      internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                                ^
Error: Cannot find package '@/app' imported from C:\Users\hardb\Documents\gitlab-projects\assisterr-app\src\middleware.ts
    at packageResolve (C:\Users\hardbb\Documents\gitlab-projects\assisterr-app\node_modules\.pnpm\ts-node@10.9.2_@types+node@20.14.5_typescript@5.4.5\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:757:9)
    at moduleResolve (C:\Users\hardb\Documents\gitlab-projects\assisterr-app\node_modules\.pnpm\ts-node@10.9.2_@types+node@20.14.5_typescript@5.4.5\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:798:18)
    at Object.defaultResolve (C:\Users\hardb\Documents\gitlab-projects\assisterr-app\node_modules\.pnpm\ts-node@10.9.2_@types+node@20.14.5_typescript@5.4.5\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:912:11)    
    at C:\Users\hardb\Documents\gitlab-projects\assisterr-app\node_modules\.pnpm\ts-node@10.9.2_@types+node@20.14.5_typescript@5.4.5\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:218:35
    at entrypointFallback (C:\Users\hardb\Documents\gitlab-projects\assisterr-app\node_modules\.pnpm\ts-node@10.9.2_@types+node@20.14.5_typescript@5.4.5\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:168:34)
    at C:\Users\hardb\Documents\gitlab-projects\assisterr-app\node_modules\.pnpm\ts-node@10.9.2_@types+node@20.14.5_typescript@5.4.5\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:217:14
    at addShortCircuitFlag (C:\Users\hardb\DDocuments\gitlab-projects\assisterr-app\node_modules\.pnpm\ts-node@10.9.2_@types+node@20.14.5_typescript@5.4.5\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:409:21)
    at resolve (C:\Users\hardbb\Documents\gitlab-projects\assisterr-app\node_modules\.pnpm\ts-node@10.9.2_@types+node@20.14.5_typescript@5.4.5\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:197:12)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:865:28)
    at Hooks.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:303:30)

Node.js v20.11.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

